# Make an ordinary user an admin using a script ( mac )

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

How can i generate a script that will open up the terminal, login to the local admin account using username and password then make the non-admin user an admin. Like this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIXeXoQZ6ZA) where its done manually but i want it done using a script.

I'm not sure if the terminal will take a password or username from a script, if not could someone tell me? obviously the script wont be possible then.

Comment: storing an admin password in a script is an abhorrent idea.

Comment: what would you suggest?....Because the script was going to be pushed by our EMM Solution.

Comment: your EMM solution should already have admin?